# Driver is not updation with latest value

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa, xcode11.1

**I have one filter type enum**

import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

```
enum FilterType {
    case all
    case rental
    case purchased
}

var currentCategory: Driver<FilterType> = Driver.just(.all)
```

**whenever I am updating the currentCategory on segment click. like below** 
currentCategory = Driver.just(.purchased).

**I am always getting the same value all every time. I am new to RXSwift and RXCocoa. Please help me to get out of this situation. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

You are using RxSwift in incorrect way: every time when you assign to `currentCategory`, your subscriptions gets disposed. You need to use different approach:

```
let currentCategory = BehaviorRelay<FilterType>(value: .all)
```

and then in your code set new value for BehaviorRelay:

```
currentCategory.accept(.purchased)
```

or bind it to your UI control:

```
segmentControl.rx.value
  .map {
    switch $0 {
    case 0: return FilterType.all
    case 1: return FilterType.rental
    case 2: return FilterType.purchased
    default: return FilterType.all
    }
  }
  .bind(to: viewModel.currentCategory)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: I have one more doubts.    
 I have to refresh the list based on the segment control value changed 
 I have taken one  PublishSubject like below
let selectedPurchaseTabSegmentPublisher = PublishSubject< FilterType >()
I don't know how to achieve this using publish subject.  Could anyone please help me?